# Detect fullscreen menu bar movement

Tags: objective-c, macos, statusbar

So right now I have an NSWindow that draws itself like an NSToolbar using [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow/), and I was wondering if there was any kind of event or message sent out when the menu bar moves while the app is in full screen, so that I could then move the title bar of the window in response (the way a standard NSToolbar works).  Clearly NSToolbar knows something that I don't, and it would save me from making an NSTrackingArea on the upper part of my window.

Here's what it does now:

[image: Before]

And here's what I'd like to do:

[image]

Unfortunately, KVO'ing a `fullScreenAccessoryView` does not work as well.  Frame events are only generated when entering and exiting fullscreen mode, and not when the toolbar is "moved down" by the status bar.

Comment: When you say “status bar”, do you actually mean the menu bar?

Comment: Yes.  It goes by many names (Apple calls it [NSStatusBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).

Comment: In general, the menu bar is fixed at the top of the user's monitor.  Is this menu bar at the top of the moving window? Now that I'm doing a 2nd & 3rd read of your question, I'm guessing this is a iTunes / Xcode like toolbar at the top of your window. Maybe append a screenshot to your question so we have a better idea of what you're talking about?

Comment: I think he's talking about the way the menu bar hides when you put a window in fullscreen mode, and then reappears if you move your mouse pointer to the top edge of the screen.  If you do this in Safari or Xcode (for example), the toolbar will slide down to stay fully visible.

Comment: Obviously the iTunes team didn't get the memo, because its toolbar doesn't slide down. :)

Comment: Well, both the `[NSMenu menuBarVisible]` and `[[NSApplication sharedApplication].mainMenu.menuBarHeight]` reflects the visual state of the menu bar, but in my tests, menuBarHeight neither menuBarVisible are KVO compliant, meaning there's no way to animate 'correctly' =/

Comment: Looks like NSToolBar is the widget that gives you this functionality automatically... (which would explain why it's broken in iTunes)

Comment: @nielsbot: I know that ;). This question is here precisely because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Create `NSStatusBarItem` with a custom `NSView` having width `0` and then track its `window`'s position using `NSWindowWillMoveNotification`.

UPDATE: I made a fork of the [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow/) with a custom toolbar attached to the menubar. [Check it out](https://github.com/shpakovski/INAppStoreWindow/commit/3b92672ee3c04f93cdc7f06ff29c8d999f37e6fd).

Comment: Actually, this might be what I'm looking for.  Give me a minute to test it out.

Comment: Nope, no dice.  The window gives off absolutely no notifications, and NSNotificationCenter subscriptions yield nothing.  Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Then you have no other choice than change UI to use a standard `NSToolbar` (with `fullScreenAccessoryView` if it improves UX). It looks like even iTunes team did not manage how to note the `NSStatusBar` movement.

Comment: Wow, that's quite a bit of effort on your part for my question.  The bounty is yours, @Stream.

Comment: Thank you @CodaFi. But I'm still suggesting you to consider the standard NSToolbar :)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is to use set a fake (i.e. empty) toolbar on the window and then give it a `fullScreenAccessoryView`. This view is, when moving into fullscreen, removed from the view hierarchy and attached below the toolbar. Dunno, however, how this is works when using a custom window class... :/

Comment: Then KVO the toolbar rect... Hmm interesting proposal.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, and with INAppStoreWindow, actually creates a weird upper bar portion.  Thank you for your answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to accomplish exactly the same thing. I was able to do it by setting the superview of the titlebar view in a [WAYAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/weAreYeah/WAYAppStoreWindow/) (or INAppStoreWindow) to post frame change notifications and then observing frame change notifications on this view. Add the following observer in your setup:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(windowTitleBarFrameDidChange:)
                                             name:NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification
                                           object:window.titleBarView.superview];
```

And turn on/off frame change notifications when entered/exiting full-screen:

```
window.titleBarView.superview.postsFrameChangedNotifications = YES;
```

Then in the implementation of the `windowTitleBarFrameWillChange:` method, check to see when the titlebar will show by comparing with the last y position of it’s superview’s frame. Here is the code:

```
// Window titlebar heights.
#define kWindowTitlebarHeightDefault    22.0
#define kWindowTitlebarHeightStandard   37.0
#define kWindowTitlebarHeightExtended   82.0

- (void) windowTitleBarFrameDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    NSView * titleBarView = [notification object];  // view is actually the titlebar container view

    if (NSMinX(_lastTitleBarFrame) == NSMinX(titleBarView.frame) &&
        NSWidth(_lastTitleBarFrame) == NSWidth(titleBarView.frame) &&
        NSHeight(_lastTitleBarFrame) == NSHeight(titleBarView.frame) &&
        NSMinY(_lastTitleBarFrame) == -kWindowTitlebarHeightDefault &&
        NSMinY(titleBarView.frame) > -kWindowTitlebarHeightDefault)                     // titlebar will show
    {
        [self windowTitleBarWillShow];
    }
    else if (NSMinX(_lastTitleBarFrame) == NSMinX(titleBarView.frame) &&
             NSWidth(_lastTitleBarFrame) == NSWidth(titleBarView.frame) &&
             NSHeight(_lastTitleBarFrame) == NSHeight(titleBarView.frame) &&
             NSMinY(_lastTitleBarFrame) == 0.0 && NSMinY(titleBarView.frame) < 0.0)     // titlebar will hide
    {
        [self windowTitleBarWillHide:YES];
    }
    else if (NSWidth(_lastTitleBarFrame) != NSWidth([NSScreen mainScreen].frame) &&
             NSWidth(titleBarView.frame) == NSWidth([NSScreen mainScreen].frame))       // just went full-screen
    {
        [self windowTitleBarWillHide:NO];
    }

    _lastTitleBarFrame = titleBarView.frame;
}

- (void) windowTitleBarWillHide:(BOOL)animate
{
    WAYAppStoreWindow * window = (WAYAppStoreWindow *)[(NSWindowController *)[[self windowControllers] objectAtIndex:0] window];
    NSView * themeFrame = window.titleBarView.superview.superview;    
    if (animate)
        [themeFrame animator].alphaValue = 0.0;
    else
        themeFrame.alphaValue = 0.0;
}

- (void) windowTitleBarWillShow
{
    WAYAppStoreWindow * window = (WAYAppStoreWindow *)[(NSWindowController *)[[self windowControllers] objectAtIndex:0] window];
    NSView * themeFrame = window.titleBarView.superview.superview;
    [themeFrame animator].alphaValue = 1.0;
}

- (void) windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    WAYAppStoreWindow * window = [notification object];
    [self setUpFullScreenTitleBarForWindow:window];
    _lastTitleBarFrame = NSZeroRect;
}

- (void) windowDidEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    WAYAppStoreWindow * window = [notification object];
    window.titleBarView.superview.postsFrameChangedNotifications = YES;
    _fullscreenToolbarView.hidden = NO;
}

- (void) windowWillExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification;
{
    WAYAppStoreWindow * window = [notification object];
    window.titleBarView.superview.postsFrameChangedNotifications = NO;
    [self setUpStandardTitleBarForWindow:window];
}

- (void) setUpNormalTitleBarForWindow:(WAYAppStoreWindow *)window
{
    window.appearance = nil;
    window.showsTitle = NO;
    window.titleBarHeight = kWindowTitlebarHeightExtended;
    window.verticalTrafficLightButtons = YES;
    window.centerTrafficLightButtons = YES;
    window.trafficLightButtonsLeftMargin = 13.0;

    _fullscreenToolbarView.hidden = YES;
}

- (void) setUpFullScreenTitleBarForWindow:(WAYAppStoreWindow *)window
{
    window.appearance = [NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark];
    window.showsTitle = YES;
    window.titleBarHeight = kWindowTitlebarHeightStandard;
    window.verticalTrafficLightButtons = NO;
    window.centerTrafficLightButtons = YES;
    window.trafficLightButtonsLeftMargin = 13.0;
    window.verticallyCenterTitle = YES;

    _fullscreenToolbarView.hidden = YES;
    _lastTitleBarFrame = NSZeroRect;
}
```

NB: I’m using a fork of [WAYWindow](https://github.com/dbrisinda/WAYWindow) that adds support for vertically centring the document title in the titlebar.